# C# : Connecting to dbf file using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: c#, oledb

I am trying connect to dbf file in 64 bit os using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider.

I wrote

```
   [Test]
    public void CustomDbfReader()
    {
        string filepath = @"K:\data";

        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        string connectionString =
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;Data Source='" + filepath +"'" ;

        using (var oledbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            oledbConnection.Open();
            string stringCommadn = string.Format(@"select * from filename.dbf");
            var oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(stringCommadn, oledbConnection);
            var oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter
                                       {
                                           SelectCommand = oleDbCommand
                                       };
            oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(dataTable.Rows);
    }
```

I get this exception

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException : The Microsoft Access database
>   engine could not find the object 'CardifOrigin.dbf'. Make sure the
>   object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
>   If 'CardifOrigin.dbf' is not a local object, check your network
>   connection or contact the server administrator.

I am sure both path and file name exist.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dbase rules for names force a max of `10 characters`. In Approach, information about longer names is stored in a special index that Microsoft doesn't know about.

The 12 character one is the one that doesn't work. If you rename it to 8 characters, then it works fine.

[The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object filename](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209685)

> In Microsoft Access, when you import a dBase, FoxPro, or Paradox file
> that does not follow the MS-DOS 8.3 file name format (that is, its
> name before the period exceeds eight characters, or it lacks a
> three-character extension following the period), you may receive the
> following error message:
>
> The Microsoft Jet database engine could not
> find the object filename. Make sure the object exists and that you
> spell its name and the path name correctly.